# Adding response headers in Azure Powershell Function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-powershell

I have an API that only responds back in XML and I need to send the response the AZ PS function is receiving back out to the originating AZ function requester.

However in order to do so I need to set the content type.

I saw [this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-script/blob/d485616f4919fa22e984365a82fd3fab12869692/sample/HttpTrigger/index.js#L24) example but it's in JS and I'm not really sure how the headers should be added to the output object, I tried adding them as note properties but that didn't do much.

Answer (score 0):

If you follow the expected HTTP Response format as documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#http-triggers-and-bindings), you can manage response properties like headers by using like in the following example:

```
$html = "<HEAD><TITLE>Hello world</TITLE></HEAD>"
$result = [string]::Format('{{ "Status": 200, "Body": "{0}", "Headers": {{ 
"content-type": "text/html" }} }}', $html)
Out-File -Encoding Ascii $res -inputObject $result;
```

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that but I didn't want to mix the headers with the data queried in the same JSON. In the end I ended up looping through each node of the XML adding it as a property to a custom object and then converting that to JSON.

Comment: Yes, that's another approach to do the same. Essentially, if your response contains a JSON formatted object in that follows the expected response format, it will be treated as such.

Comment: Please mark this as answer if it addresses your question.